# How to add widgets to the grid with max row of elements

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt, gxt

I have long `AarrayList<Image> imageList`. When I'm trying to put every image from this list to the Grid as result I have only latest image.

My code:

```
final int columnCount =3; //max images in the row
        final int rowCount = (int) Math.ceil((double) data.size()/columnCount);

    Grid grid = new Grid(rowCount, columnCount);

    for (int i=0; i< imageList.size(); i++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < columnCount; col++) {
                grid.setWidget(row, col, imageList.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Could you help me to resolve this issue

Comment: I would say that in this case the method _setWidget_ should have been called only once or it is overriding the same image which means that the row and column should be the same which seems to be impossible. Did you try to debug? Do we call setWidget once or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a logical error in your for-loop.
you are always just overriding the elements with the last image in `imageList`

you could try something like this:

```
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    for (Image image : imageList) {
        grid.setWidget(row, col, image);
        col++;
        if (col > 2) {
            col = 0;
            row++;
        }
    }
```